# How can I constrain a subview so that it cannot be dragged outside of it's parent view's bounds. (iOS)

Tags: xcode, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, subview

How to constrain the position of a subview within its parent view. I have a subview within a UIView. The subview can be dragged via gesture recognizer. How can I constrain the subview so that it cannot be dragged outside of it's parent view's bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to constrain a draggable view, you need to check for its position while you move it and then force it to the constrained position if it exceeds the boundaries. So assuming you use `touchesMoved` :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    ...

    CGRect frame = mySubview.frame; 
    if (frame.origin.x < boundaryX) { //frame exceeds the horizontal boundary
        frame.origin.x = boundaryX;
        mySubview.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

so assuming boundaryX is the origin of the parent view then this way the subview will never exceed that boundary. You need to do the same for origin `y` and `x + width` and `y + height` to do constraints from all sides.

hope this helps.

Comment: What if the parent view is a circle?