# How do I intercept mapview panning and zooming (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to restrict panning and zooming for a mapview, to remain within a predefined max and min camera altitude and the four corners of a bounding box.

[The solutions proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling), allow the user to pan outside the region, and then use `regionDidChangeAnimated` to pan them back to within the pre-defined bounds.

I'd like to know if it's possible to just never allow the user to pan outside the bounds in the first place. Can I, for example, intercept panning/zooming gestures and decide whether or not to let them continue?

I think I'm looking for something like the following pseudocode:

```
func blockMapViewPanEvent(_ mapView: MKMapView){
    return mapView.visibleMapRect.isContainedWithin(topLeft, bottomRight)
}
```

I know that MapBox's Swift SDK achieves this, so I imagine it's possible. Can I do this with plain-old MapKit?

**Edit for Clarity:**

I want to restrict panning and zooming so the user can pan and zoom as much as they want **within a bounding box**. For example, if the bounding box is of Germany, I want the user to be able to pan and zoom within Germany, but they should never be able to see Spain, since Spain is outside the bounding box of Germany.

I do not want to disable all user interaction on the map view.

Comment: @DaniSpringer I'm not programmatically updating the map location at all. I think I'm trying to figure out how to do exactly what you're describing: intercept the pan, check the new position, and ignore it if it does not meet some criteria. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539521/how-can-i-constrain-a-subview-so-that-it-cannot-be-dragged-outside-of-its-paren?rq=1

Comment: @DaniSpringer I've referenced that first link in the question and stated how this question differs to that, and the answers provided there. Specificaly:

"The solutions proposed here, allow the user to pan outside the region, and then use `regionDidChangeAnimated` to pan them back to within the pre-defined bounds.

I'd like to know if it's possible to just never allow the user to pan outside the bounds in the first place."

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt that code, by changing the lines that would "check if out of region, and if yes, move back", to "check if the new location of pan is outside of region, and if yes, ignore pan gesture". The way pan gesture works is the phone detects a movement (gesture) and provides its data to the app. So the app can handle that so that if the data provided show that the new location to update the element to (in this case, a map) is beyond a certain limit (more or less than something), you can do something about it, for example: ignore it entirely, and not update the element's position.

Comment: I use this for draggable textfields: `@objc func myFunc(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myTextField)
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        myTextFieldXConstraint.constant = myTextFieldXConstraint.constant + translation.x
        myTextFieldYConstraint.constant = myTextFieldYConstraint.constant + translation.y
        myTextField.center = CGPoint(x: myTextField.center.x + translation.x, y: myTextField.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    }`

Comment: So for the map, I'd try to add a line of code before "myTextField.center" that reads something like "if translation.x is less than 100 AND translation.y is less than 200..." then set the `.center` of the element to the new value, so that if the user tried to go out of bounds, the gesture will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to disable user interaction in the map.

Here are the few options available in map view. These might be helpful for you

```
mapView.zoomEnabled = false
mapView.scrollEnabled = false
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

If you have issues with these you can simply put a transparent view over map view

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. I want the user to be able to pan and zoom **within a certain area**. They should not be able to pan/zoom outside that area. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I think the question asks how to allow panning and zooming but only within a desired area.